# How to read fixedDelayMinutes from yml file and shedule the job in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler, job-scheduling, cron-task

I want to read value from yml in minutes and then in scheduler give the value in milliseconds

e.g. for 5 min
5 * 60 * 1000

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${jobintervalmins} * 60 * 1000")
I have tried like this, but it is not working

I am getting error :  Invalid fixedDelayString value "5 * 60 * 1000" - cannot parse into long

properties file will contain
jobintervalmins: 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specifically have it interpret the value as minutes, but you can have it parsed as a `Duration`. The string value is parsed to a long using [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4a13928a2721259f9f4cf06814a6cfee6667bbb5/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L530-L535):

```java
private static long parseDelayAsLong(String value) throws RuntimeException {
    if (value.length() > 1 && (isP(value.charAt(0)) || isP(value.charAt(1)))) {
        return Duration.parse(value).toMillis();
    }
    return Long.parseLong(value);
}
```

If the value has a `P` as its first or second character, it'll be turned into a long using [`Duration.parse(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). For example, a value of 5 minutes can be expressed as `PT5M`.

You could configure your annotation to use `${jobinterval}`:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${jobinterval}")
```

You can then specify a numeric value in your yaml file that will be used as milliseconds:

```yaml
jobinterval: 30000
```

Or you can specify a textural representation of a duration using whatever unit you want:

```yaml
jobinterval: PT5M
jobinternal: PT300S
```

Comment: I want to give the jobinterval in minutes like , jobinterval: 5, Then I want to calculate the minute into milliseconds in the annotation. Is it possible

Comment: No, that's not possible. The value of the annotation either has to be a number of milliseconds or a string that can be parsed into a duration. `PT5M`, which is how `Duration` parsing expects 5 minutes to be represented, is the closest you can get.